# on ajax page galleria gallery not loading correctly

Tags: ajax, loading, galleria

http://www.pad10.com/my_dir/pad10/

here when we click it on any sub category(catalogs,websites....etc). we will get project name. when we click on project name (Diary Collection 2011) galleria should open. at the first click galleria is loading correctly. my issue is that when we click on 2nd project galleria not loading . it work only with first click. here subcategory listing,project listing, and galleria loading page is ajax loaded. i put the galleria code on index.php. if we call individual galleria page it is working correctly.

please help how i can solve this issue.